# Two columns on the same property

Tags: entity-framework

I have a database table called `Person` having this columns `{id, first_name, last_name}`. Than I have a read model called `PersonView` having only two properties `Id` and `Nominative`. I have a mapping for this type:

```
public class PersonViewMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<PersonView>
{
    public PersonViewMapping()
    {
        this.ToTable("Person", "schema");
        this.HasKey(d => d.id);
    }
}
```

In this mapping I would say map the concatenation of `Person.first_name` and `Person.last_name` to `PersonView.Nominative`.
How can I do that?

Comment: Use an unmapped property and write the code in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to build your model as of the database, if you have to save the first and last name then you entity must have those two properties. so in your case as I understand ... you need to write your class as below

```
 public class PersonView
 {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Firstname { get; set; }
     public string Lastname { get; set; }
     public string Nominative { get { return string.Concat(this.Firstname, " ", this.Lastname); } }
 }
```

and in your configuration just Ignore that property

```
public class PersonViewMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<PersonView>
{
    public PersonViewMapping()
    {
        this.ToTable("Person");
        this.HasKey(d => d.Id);
        this.Property(d => d.Firstname);
        this.Property(d => d.Lastname);
        this.Ignore(d => d.Nominative);
    }
}
```

Comment: why you want to avoid this kind of properties

Comment: Maybe avoiding is not the correct word. I thought there was a way to do this directly using EF.

Comment: adding redundancy data in db is not good .. unless it's mandatory for some reason... so in your case I think that it's not that much important to save the full name in the database ... you can use these kind of properties for your business need.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it this way, without mapping, as your nomination is not the actual field in your table and for this mapping not required.

```
public abstract class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "First name cannot be longer than 50 characters.")]
    [Column("FirstName")]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstMidName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Full Name")]
    public string FullName
    {
        get
        {
            return LastName + ", " + FirstMidName;
        }
    }
}
```